# Pass current loggedin user id in lookup field in lightning component

Tags: lightning, lookup, create-records

Eximanie Record field is a user lookup and i want to populate this lookup value as current logged in user, but it is showing still blank on lightning component.

```
({
    doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
    var action = component.get("c.Merge");
    var Recordtypeid = "0123A000001O3CT";
    action.setParams({"RecordId": Recordtypeid});
    
   var userId = $A.get("$SObjectType.CurrentUser.Id");
   
   action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var resp = response.getReturnValue();           
        component.set("v.mergeOpt",resp);
        var record = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");
           record.setParams(
            { 
                "entityApiName": "CustomAsset__c",
                "recordTypeId" : Recordtypeid,
                "defaultFieldValues": {
                    'count__c' : 100,
                    'Eximanie_RecordId__c' : userId, 
                },
            }
        ); 
        var dismissActionPanel = $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction"); 
        dismissActionPanel.fire();
        record.fire();
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

})

Comment: Since you're calling an Apex class anyway, why not get the running user's ID there instead?  This task would be much more straightforward in Apex: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_userinfo.htm#apex_System_UserInfo_getUserId

Comment: You mean to say `$A.get("$SObjectType.CurrentUser.Id");` is coming as blank?

Comment: do you have any field on your CustomAsset__c object with api name **count**?

Comment: @sanketkumar- no, i missed __c

Comment: @NagendraSingh- yes it is coming as blank